# Invalid Host Header when trying to access the react.js application deployed on EC2 using AWS application Load balancer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elb

i made a react js app and deployed it on ec2 . it is accessible by ec2 public ip and port number but when i try to attatch a load balancer to the instance i cannot access it by the static lb dns as it shows invalid host header . where should i make change in either the aws component configuration or my react app code. If I am making new react app just by create-react-app react_app_name and add this to target group this is becoming accessible by that DNS of Load balancer

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.13.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Already tried making changes in package.json

"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start --disable-host-check",
}